# SyntaxError: '#companySize option:selected' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML and jQuery code.

It shows me an error `"SyntaxError: '#companySize option:selected' is not a valid selector"` while I have **opened the developer console of the browser (i.e. while I do Inspect Element)** and crash my system. How can I solve it?

```js
var customerSegment = $("#companySize option:selected").val();
console.log(customerSegment);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="companySize">
 <option value="0">Select Customer Segment</option>
 <option value="1"> 1 - 100 </option>
 <option value="2"> 100 - 200 </option>
 <option value="3"> 200 - 300 </option>
 <option value="4"> 300 - above</option>
</select>
```

Comment: On which browser are you testing this? It is not happening on my system.

Comment: $("#companySize").val() is enough for your requirment.

Comment: I was testing on Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Which version of Firefox ? I'm on Firefox 55 and there is no error.

Comment: its 56.0.2 @ADreNaLiNe-DJ

Comment: You should test the result of calling $("#companySize option:selected") before you try to call .val(), like any function it may not return what you are expecting.

Comment: Just tested on 56.0.2 and it works flawlessly

Comment: are you able to see the error in above snippet in your browser??

Comment: Error was when I did inspect element. :)

Comment: @KiranShahi and which `selector` do you use to inspect element ? Because your code is not faulty but what you put in the console to inspect is the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run your code inside `$('select#companySize').on('change', function()` because first load page its default value is 0 so after `onchange of select` its value get so it will work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select#companySize').on('change', function() {
    var customerSegment = $("#companySize option:selected").val();
    console.log(customerSegment);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="companySize">
 <option value="0">Select Customer Segment</option>
 <option value="1"> 1 - 100 </option>
 <option value="2"> 100 - 200 </option>
 <option value="3"> 200 - 300 </option>
 <option value="4"> 300 - above</option>
</select>
```